# credentials error when running a playbook

Tags: ansible-awx

I'm trying to run a simple ping playbook on a windows host, but it gives me the following error:

- "unreachable": true,
  "msg": "basic: the specified credentials were rejected by the server",
  "changed": false*

Here we can see the listener configuration:
[listenerconf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGmti.png)

my settings within awx inventory are:

ansible_connection: winrm
ansible_winrm_transport: basic
ansible_port: 5985
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore

My password is correct, what I don't know is why it sends me this error?

validation with manufacturer's documentation